# Couldn't predict newdata using SVM in R: named numeric(0)

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, svm

I'm working on my final project. I got the result yesterday but when I tried to run it again and several errors popped up. The one that I couldn't figure out is: After training the data, I tried to predict the testing set based on the model,the training process seems fine, but the result is :named numeric(0). I have attached my code.

```
svm_st <- svm(train_result~ . , data=data.frame(a_sca_train),type="eps-
regression",kernel="radial",scale=T)
svm_st
put_test<-data.frame(a_sca_test)
predict_svm<-predict(svm_st,newdata=put_test)
predict_svm
```

And the result is:

```
> predict_svm
named numeric(0)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Laura, can you please provide some example data? Also, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

before predicting from "svm_st" model, remove "train_result" column from "put_test" dataset.